Simplest way to generate version string for Maven package from Git branch
I want to automate the version string generation for release builds of my Java project. My pom.xml has a <version>${my-version-property}</version tag and the Git branch is called e.g. release/1.0.2. How do I extract "1.0.2" from the branch name, so that I can use it as a property in downstream project dependency tags and in the <finalName> for the maven-war-plugin?
I found the buildnumber-maven-plugin that allows me so set a property to a generated string through Java's MessageFormat mechanism. Its ${scmBranch} property contains the current Git branch, but MessageFormat syntax doesn't support substrings (correct me if I'm wrong).
I found this question where one answer suggests gmaven-plugin. But I would rather not use two different plugins for this otherwise relatively simple thing. In fact, I wouldn't say I'd be reinventing the wheel if I had to write a line of source code somewhere to achieve this. However, I don't intend to make my Java project aware of the build process. What's the most straightforward approach here?

I would do it on your ci system. What do you use? Gitlab, GitHub, Jenkins?

I use GitLab CI/CD. That's a good idea. A script could update the pom.xml files.

In Gitlab CI, use something like
- mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=$RELEASE_VERSION
where your first set $RELEASE_VERSION to the right value.

Here’s how you can extract the version:
The maven-scm-plugin will retrieve the current Git branch name and make it available as the property ${scmBranch}:
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>get-branch</id>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>validate</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>

The build-helper-maven-plugin allows you to parse the branch name using a regular expression and extract the desired version. Configure it as follows:
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>extract-version</id>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>regex-property</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <name>release.version</name>
        <value>${scmBranch}</value>
        <regex>release/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)</regex>
        <replacement>$1</replacement>
        <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch> <!-- optional -->
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>


Name: The extracted version is assigned to variable release.version.
Regex Explanation: This pattern matches branches like release/1.0.2 and extracts 1.0.2 as the version.

Now that the version is extracted and set as ${release.version}, you can use it in your build configurations. For instance, to set the final name of the WAR file:
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${release.version}</finalName>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

This will create a WAR file named like my-project-1.0.2.war.

GPT answers are not allowed.

@berger-devel configuration section of the build-helper-maven-plugin corrected
